# RawInput mouse - cannot move window or use controls

Tags: c++, winapi, raw-input

I am currently using the RawInput API from Windows to get access to keyboard and mouse input.
One thing i am a little bit confused about is when i register my mouse as a `RawInputDevice` i cannot move my Win32 window or use the controls up there (close, minimize etc...). Instead i get a loading icon cursor. Is this normal behaviour?
This is how i register my device:

```
    RAWINPUTDEVICE Rid[2];

    Rid[0].usUsagePage = 0x01;
    Rid[0].usUsage = 0x02;
    Rid[0].dwFlags = RIDEV_NOLEGACY;   // adds HID mouse and also ignores legacy mouse messages
    Rid[0].hwndTarget = windowHandle;

    Rid[1].usUsagePage = 0x01;
    Rid[1].usUsage = 0x06;
    Rid[1].dwFlags = RIDEV_NOLEGACY;   // adds HID keyboard and also ignores legacy keyboard messages
    Rid[1].hwndTarget = windowHandle;

    if (RegisterRawInputDevices(Rid, 2, sizeof(Rid[0])) == FALSE) {
         // smth went wrong.
    }
```

And this is how i handle the `WM_INPUT` case:

```
case WM_INPUT:
    char buffer[sizeof(RAWINPUT)] = {};
    UINT size = sizeof(RAWINPUT);
    GetRawInputData(reinterpret_cast<HRAWINPUT>(lParam), RID_INPUT, buffer, &size, sizeof(RAWINPUTHEADER));
    RAWINPUT* raw = reinterpret_cast<RAWINPUT*>(buffer);
    if (raw->header.dwType == RIM_TYPEMOUSE || raw->header.dwType == RIM_TYPEKEYBOARD) {
        inputManager.processMessage(*raw);
    }
    break;
```

Is there something wrong?

Comment: Yes, as it's not working as you intended. What have you worked out so far?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are setting the `RIDEV_NOLEGACY` flag.  This disables legacy mouse messages.

Hence the default window procedure doesn't receive mouse messages.  So it can't move your window, or respond to button clicks, or whatever.  Which is what you are seeing.